# How to set Intellisense of Visual Studio2010 about c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, intellisense, visual-c++-6

Intellisense of Visual Studio2010 about C# is strong,
but no intellisense about c++ project,
How to set Intellisense of Visual Studio2010 about c++ ?

Comment: Is this in reference to C++/CLI?

Comment: It probably is, given that VS2010 dropped support for it and supports IS for native C++ just fine.  Back in VS2012.